# Is it possible to catch all the Leaf Green Pokemon using a Gameboy emulator?

Tags: emulation, pokemon-third-generation

I am currently playing Pokemon Leaf Green on a GameBoy Advance emulator. Is there any way to catch all the Pokemon?

I understand that to get all the Pokemon, you need to trade to get Pokemon that are not found in Leaf Green. Is there any way to interface with another game to trade on an emulator? Or is that just not possible and I won't be able to catch'em all?

Comment: You might want to split your questions - you are both asking for a list of LeafGreen Pokemon, and also for a way to interface with trade - I edited it to be just about the emulation. I wouldn't really advise asking about the list here, though - it is pretty easy to find with a quick Google search, and it would be a list answer, so it would probably get closed pretty fast.

Comment: It's itemized lists that are bad, where the list is a set of answers each containing one item. One answer containing a complete list is fine. That said I agree that they're separate questions and the list is too basic (general reference).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is actually a special emulator you can use to trade between games called [VBALink](http://www.vbalink.info/) (and is based off of Visual Boy Advanced). If you had another game, you could trade between copies and get all of the Pokemon.

An alternate is to use cheats to "encounter" them in the wild, which most all emulators provide built in.

Comment: Hm, I wonder if there aren't some patches out there simply turning e.g. red/blue to "purple" containing both games' pokemon...

Comment: @Zommuter There are a lot of custom ROMs out there for Pokemon, and one game containing both are the smaller mods to find. Linking to ROMs is not allowed, but if you are interested, they are very easy to find, and mods range from additional Pokemon/areas to full rewrites of the games.

Comment: Good point, there are quite enthusiastic projects like Ash Gray and Eevee Edition out there... If only I had the time to catch them all

Answer (score 0):

You can use gameshark codes in any decent emulator. This is probably an easier way to get them all (even shiny, if you'd like) compared to finding someone willing to play the emulator game to trade with you.

Last time I checked, VBALink wasn't newbieproof and "requires some assembly", if you know what I mean.

Comment: VBALink isn't *that* hard to set up, a crash course in basic networking or instructions on a Youtube video would suffice.