# How can I evolve trade Pokemon like Kadabra using the VBA Emulator?

Tags: emulation, pokemon-fire-red-leaf-green

I want to evolve Kadabra in Fire Red (using vba) and noticed that in the videos people used they simply were using the link option. But my problem is that the VBA emulator I have was a different version without the link option. How do i

- Evolve Kadabra on my current vba, or
- Open the same GBA file on VBA 1.8 (which has the link option)?

Comment: What's your current VBA version ?

Comment: Side note: If you want to evade the evolve-by-trading problem, you can use rom ramdomizers. They are usually used to randomize Pokemon encounters and such, but there is also an option to have Kadabra etc. evolve at a certain level while keeping everything else vanilla. Note: This must be done before starting a game! AFAIK you cannot edit a rom and continue an earlier save.

Comment: My answer here might help: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/168187/can-i-trade-between-pokemon-red-gen-i-and-pokemon-crystal-gen-ii-via-vba-on/388155#388155

Answer (score 3):

You can use VBA Link.

It's a different version from the regular VBA, it supports using up to 4 player connection.

You will need to change your save data format, from .SAV to .SA1 (you can change it from .SA1 to .SA4, the number being the respective player).

Once you do all the trading you need change your save file back to .SAV to keep playing in your regular emulator.

I recommend to do a back up of your save file just in case things go wrong so you don't lose any progress.

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves, the VGA does not support emulating link cables.

I believe some of the Nintendo DS emulators can emulate multiple connected gameboy NDs).

check if your savefiles (not quicksaves, actual saves) can work on both systems, then you could load your savefile on a more complex emulator, play a second gamesate until you reacha  tradepoint, trade the pokemon, evolve it and trade it back, save and load in your old emulator.